# Does the "protected" keyword has anything at all to do with multi-threading?

Tags: c#

Since I my very first days as a C# programmer, I was taught that the *protected* keyword was an accessibility modifier that was relevant for (mostly) derived classes. It was never, on my understanding, something related to threads.

However, a colleague of mine insists, with all of his vehemency, that this keyword actually makes an object "protected from  multi-threading issues", and thus he marks every single property or field that may be used in a thread as *protected*.

I've already showed him the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx) regarding the protected keyword. His reaction was that the documentation is wrong.

We are fighting over it for more than a year now. He seems so certain of what he says that I'm starting to doubt myself on what I know about this specific keyword.

So,

**Does the *protected* keyword has anything to do with threads, at all?**

Comment: nope it doesn't

Comment: "His reaction was that the documentation is wrong." Hilarious!

Comment: Your colleague is completely and utterly mistaken, not just about C# but about life in general.  That your employer retains such an employee is a very telling problem and you may do well to find a better job in which you work with competent and professional colleagues from whom you might be able to learn things.

Comment: I'm curious to know, what are these "multi-threading issues" of which he thinks `protected` "protects" against?

Comment: If the keyword had anything to do with multithreading, locks, semaphores, etc. and protected anything in this way, *it would be the default behavior* and you would need to use a keyword similar to `unsafe` to override it.

Comment: Also, who does he think wrote the documentation?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I think it's pretty clear this is a conspiracy of microsoft versus his colleague... I wonder how it all started

Comment: That would be pretty awesome if we could just apply a single keyword to protect our code from "multi-threading issues". As an exercise, challenge your colleague to identify the specific "multi-threading issues" that he believes are prevented from this keyword.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Clippy stole his girlfriend in middle school.

Comment: @squillman Mostly concurrent access issues. The rationale is that since the property/field is "protected", it can't be messed up by concurrent access. Because, you know, a single keyword can solve one of the worst problems of computing.

Comment: Maybe he meant the volatile keyword?

Comment: My favorite part is that in the entire "year" during which this argument has taken place, the colleague has presented *zero* evidence of this claim.  Not one example which demonstrates a "threading issue" which is thus resolved by the use of the `protected` keyword.  Your colleague should consider a career in politics.

Comment: Maybe he's confused with `volatile`, `lock`, or the Java keyword `synchronized`.

Comment: @Dennis_E No, he is not. I use those on my code on a regular basis, and already showed them to him. Then I got _"protected volatile"_ stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has nothing to do with threads and multithreading.

`protected` is just access modifier meaning "can be accessed in instance of this class and derived classes".